# Human readable text for current weather condition

Tags: linux, command-line, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices, weather

I am looking for a command line program that takes the current weather condition from a website and prints it out in a human readable format.

Actually, I have a Linux box which is connected to my TV and is always on. Sometimes the TV is not on but I want to know about the weather condition without turning the TV on. My idea is to pipe the output of the weather command to the text to speech command, e.g., `weather-condition | espeak` and assign a short-cut to the command.

So, I can get the info from the speakers rather than the screen. A python script would be perfect, but any other linux-runnable command would suffice.

Comment: what about a so called `Radio`  ?

Comment: @Endoro: Link to it's website, please.

Comment: simply put the word `RADIO` in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Linux utility seems to be exactly what you asked for.

http://fungi.yuggoth.org/weather

> This command-line utility is intended to provide quick access to current weather conditions and forecasts. Presently, it is capable of returning data for localities throughout the USA and some select locations globally by retrieving and formatting decoded METARs (Meteorological Aerodrome Reports) from NOAA (the USA National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration) and forecasts/alerts from NWS (the USA National Weather Service). The tool is written to function in the same spirit as other command-line informational utilities like cal(1), calendar(1) and dict(1). It retrieves arbitrary weather data via precompiled correlations or custom-tailored aliases (system-wide or on a per-user basis). It can be freely used and redistributed under the terms of a BSD-like License.